# Stuck with saving my form to a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have connected my html to mysql and it connects properly

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

But now, I am stuck, completely, just confused really, so let me explain this the best I can.
Here is the div, where my form data is portrayed onto a page, for the user to read, I want to save these on the page so they're there for everyone to read when the page is reloaded (Don't worry it doesn't reveal any personal information) so here's the div.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="submissions">
    <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Question.</h2>
<div class="checkboxes"><?= !empty($_GET['x']) ? $_GET['x'] : '' ?>
</div>

    </div>

<div class="top-submit"><?php echo '&#8220;' . (!empty($_GET['actual-question']) ? $_GET['actual-question'] : '') . '&#8221;';?>
</div>
<div class="poster"><?php echo "-" .  (!empty($_GET['poster']) ? $_GET['poster'] :'');?>
<div class = "like">
<a href = "javascript:countClicksLike();" class = "btn btn-large" style = "color:green;">Like</a>
<p id = "like" style = "color:green;">0</p>
</div>
<div class = "dislike">
<a href = "javascript:countClicks();" class = "btn btn-large" style = "float:right; color:red;">Dislike</a>
<p id = "dis" style = "color:red;">0</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here's the confusion, everything is working perfectly up to this point, I am connected to mysql, my form data is portraying good for me, but I want to save it to a database for everyone to see, here's where the brick wall stands.

is it something like this? I feel that I am completely wrong, sorry if anything messes me up its databases.

```
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO submissions (actual-question, poster, like, dislike) VALUES (".
     PrepSQL('actual-question') . ", " .
     PrepSQL('poster') . ", " .
     PrepSQL('like') . ", " .
     PrepSQL('dislike') . "

)";

function PrepSQL($value)
{
// Stripslashes
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
{
    $value = stripslashes($value);
}

// Quote
$value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";

return($value);
} 
?>
```

I just want to save the div to the database so it portrays on the page for everyone to see, can anyone help, I GREATLY appreciate any assistance you can give.

Thanks!

-Connor

Comment: **Hint** : `like` is a reserved word. Surround it with backticks on your query.

Comment: It appears as if you're simply trying to write static strings to the database (data from for the insert needs to come from `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables). And you're not even executing the SQL; you're just creating a string. I'd say check out some beginner MySQL & PHP tutorials, try them out, then come back with any questions.

Answer (score 0):

**** Edit ****

The PrepSQL function call in your your insert statement should be edited to pass the values collected from $_GET or $_POST
so before $sql = "..." you should save these 'prepared' values into variables then use them within your insert statement, like the below:

```
$actualQuestion = PrepSQL($_GET['actual-question']);
$poster = PrepSQL($_GET['poster']);
$like = PrepSQL($_GET['like']);
$dislike = PrepSQL($_GET['dislike']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO submissions (actual-question, poster, like, dislike) VALUES ({$actualQuestion},{$poster},{$like},{$dislike})";
```

As you can see above, we took the values from $_GET then we passed them to your PrepSQL function then saved the result into variables, and finally mixed them to your Insert statement. Now you have the insert statement ready, you can call mysql_query to actually insert your record into mysql, as mentioned within my origin solution post.

---

You wrote the insert sql statement and saved it into a variable , but you forgot to call mysql to insert the record into database. So after the $sql statement, write this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result)
    echo "Insert passed";
else
    echo "Insert failed";
```

Even though this code will do the record insertion, it is highly recommended to use the Improved PHP MySQL extension MySQLi for all your mysql database manipulation.

This link will give you a great start point to learn mysqli 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Comment: So do I keep or delete everything from the function on? Thanks for the reply by the way.